# Capistrano commands

Tags: ruby, zip, capistrano3

Can anyone tell me why the following command will not work.

```
execute :zip, :'-r', './version/files/fullsite.zip', :'.',:' -x', :'./version/*'
```

The linux version of this is

```
zip -r ./version/files/fullsite.zip . -x./version/\*
```

The aim is to zip a selection of folders and files, and exclude the ./version folder. in the linux command line, it works fine, but through the Capistrano, the version folder is always there.
I also tried the following:

```
execute :zip, :'-r', './version/files/fullsite.zip . -x ./version/\*'
```

and

```
execute :zip, :'-r', './version/files/fullsite.zip . -x ./version/*'
```

which also does not exclude the version folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quiet simple, but can catch you out, needing to read between the lines, there should be no space after the -x
so infact the correct answer to this is as follows:

```
execute :zip, :'-r', './version/files/fullsite.zip . -x./version/*'
```

Also works

```
execute :zip, :'-r', './version/files/fullsite.zip . -x ./version/\*'
```

And so does this

```
execute :zip, :'-r', './version/files/fullsite.zip', :'.',:' -x./version/*'
```

I feel so dumb now, but might be good indicator for people with the same or other problems like this.